# Is this a good use of the ?? operator?

Tags: c#, wpf

Hi the program iam working on is currently using if, else for solving the issue of filling wrong value to a textbox:

```
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(kundInformation.orgnr))
            tbxOrgNr.TextBox.Text = kundInformation.orgnr;
        else
            tbxOrgNr.TextBox.Text = "";
```

I have never personally used the ?? befor but since it is hundreds of similar lines of code in the application its really hard to read. Could it be better to use:

```
tbxOrgNr.TextBox.Text = kundInformation.orgnr ?? "";
```

Comment: You'll get another result. In first examle, if `kundInformation.orgnr` contains only white-space characters, they will change on empty string. But in second case, doesn't

Comment: @Sivasubramanian: The WPF tag is motivated as a pure WPF solution would probably be the cleanest. So your edit is imho invalid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. `??` only checks for null and not empty/whitespace.

Create an extension method instead:

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static string ValueOrEmpty(this string value)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value))
            return value;
        else
            return "";

    }
}
```

Which you then can use like this:

```
tbxOrgNr.TextBox.Text = kundInformation.orgnr.ValueOrEmpty();
```

You could of course also do it the other way to produce more readable code:

```
public static class TextBoxExtensions
{
    public static void SetTextOrEmpty(this TextBox tb, string value)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value))
            tb.Text = value;
        else
            tb.Text = "";

    }
}
```

Which gives a better assignment:

```
tbxOrgNr.TextBox.SetTextOrEmpty(kundInformation.orgnr);
```

Comment: +1 Good solution, very reusable, and I always love the (ab)use of extension methods with null as a parameter.

Comment: thanks. The best way would of course be to clean the data before storing it in the data source or when retrieving it from the data source. But once those white spaces have slipped through you don't got so many options if you don't do the cleaning in the data layer.

Answer (score 5):

No. The `??` coalescing operator will only handle the `IsNull` half of the call to `IsNullOrWhiteSpace`.

---

Now, you *could* do:

```
tbxOrgNr.TextBox.Text = (kundInformation.orgnr ?? "").Trim();
```

but that's an extra call to `Trim()`, not very good for readability, and maybe not what you want to do anyway if leading/trailing whitespace is significant.

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not since `??` only checks for `null`.

You could use this instead:

```
tbxOrgNr.TextBox.Text = 
    (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(kundInformation.orgnr)) ? kundInformation.orgnr : "";
```

Which is basically the same as your `if` statement.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but: that is not semantically equivalent; the original code will make `"    "` become `""`, because of the `OrWhiteSpace`. You could write a custom extension method, though:

```
public static string EmptyIfNullOrWhiteSpace(this string s)
{
    return string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s) ? "" : s;
}
```

then:

```
tbxOrgNr.TextBox.Text = kundInformation.orgnr.EmptyIfNullOrWhiteSpace();
```

Comment: Why has this answer received 2 down votes? That seems a bit harsh, as there is nothing incorrect here.

Comment: In the OPs situation the answer should be `No`. For the OP that is **not** "a good use of the ??-operator" simply because the statements are **not** semantically equivalent.

Comment: You are right Sheridan. This is a good answer and a similar answer received upvotes... Let's correct this.

Comment: @Sivasubramanian the OP's requirement is to simplify the existing code; the existing code **replaces 4 spaces with an empty string**, hence, that is what this answer shows.

Comment: @MarcGravell The OP's question is "Is this a good use of the ?? operator?" and then the OP shows two snippets of code and asks if it is "better to use" the second snippet as replacement for the first. In my opinion the answer is **no** since the two are not equivalent. In my opinion the answer is **not** `Yes` or `Yes, but`. Simply **No**.

Comment: @SaniHuttunen see, my "yes" is relating to the question title: "Is this a good use of the ?? operator?"; in which case I have to say, yes: that *is* a good use, as far as it being a tidy way of avoiding a `null` value; however (as I also noted), it does not behave identically to the other code. I then went on to show a compromise that simplifies the code but works identically.

Comment: @MarcGravell: I understand that you refer to the title but I still maintain that to answer the question properly one has to concider the *whole* question and not just the title.

Comment: @Sani and likewise to comment on an answer properly one has to consider the *whole* answer, and not just the first word. I have addressed **all points** of the question. Please show me something relevant in the question that I have not referred to.

Comment: @MarcGravell: Simply change `Yes, but` to `No`, `No, however` or `No, because` and you've addressed the whole question. We could argue that this is simply semantics but the distinction is significant in regards of the OP's requirements.

Comment: @SaniHuttunen I'm happy with it as written; I'm sorry that it is such a cause of concern to you

Comment: @MarcGravell It's your prerogative and not for me to decide how you should write your answer. I can only cast my vote and explain the reasons for my choice.

Answer (score 0):

You have confused the use of the ternary operator (?) with the ?? operator. Your example should use the ternary operator instead:

```
if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(kundInformation.orgnr))
    tbxOrgNr.TextBox.Text = kundInformation.orgnr;
else
    tbxOrgNr.TextBox.Text = "";
```

is the same as:

```
tbxOrgNr.TextBox.Text = (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(kundInformation.orgnr) ? 
    kundInformation.orgnr : "";
```

You can find out more about the ternary operator from the [`?`: Operator (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx) page on MSDN.

The `??` operator is different because it only checks for `null`, so

```
tbxOrgNr.TextBox.Text = kundInformation.orgnr ?? "";
```

is *actually* the same as:

```
if (kundInformation.orgnr == null) tbxOrgNr.TextBox.Text = "";
else tbxOrgNr.TextBox.Text = kundInformation.orgnr;
```

You can find out more about the `??` operator from the [`??` Operator (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx) page on MSDN.

Answer (score -1):

?? is a null-coalescing operator, so the following two pieces of code are equivalent

```
if (kundInformation.orgnr!=null)
            tbxOrgNr.TextBox.Text = kundInformation.orgnr;
        else
            tbxOrgNr.TextBox.Text = "";
```

OR:

```
tbxOrgNr.TextBox.Text = kundInformation.orgnr ?? "";
```

Note that null suppressing only checks (or replaces the usage) for null, not for empty string.

Edited as per comment. Agree with the term 'null-coalescing'

Comment: null-suppressing operator? It do not suppress null. It's a coalescing operator.